# How to make transparent only one block in a slide

Tags: transparency

I have two blocks on a slide. I simply want one block to be faded. 
I do not know why

```
 \setbeamercovered{transparent}
```

does not work.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a complete compilable example so we can test your setup.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame1}
 \setbeamercovered{transparent}
     \begin{block}{Fade this}<0>
          Some block on first slide
     \end{block}
     \begin{block}{Don't fade this}<1>
       Some other block
     \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some thing like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame1}
 \setbeamercovered{transparent}
     \begin{block}{Fade this}<1>
          Some block on first slide
     \end{block}
     \begin{block}{Don't fade this}<1-2>
       Some other block
     \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but I want one slide only. It is to say
As the slide above but only with the faded block.